# Mail storage issue

Tags: ios, storage, mobile-mail

My iPhone 6 is iOS 10.1.1 and the mail app has taken up 2 GB of space and now I can't do anything (take pics, get apps, etc). I have taken steps like deleting my mail account and rebooting the phone, but when I go to Settings it still is using 2 GB of storage.

Comment: You mean you deleted your email account completely from your phone but it still uses 2GB? What type of email account is it?

Comment: It's a gmail account

Comment: Is it the only email account on your phone?

Comment: No I had 3 gmail accounts on my phone but I deleted all of them off my phone